# how to detect if one signal is increasing in amplitude and another in decreasing at the same window

Tags: matlab

I have to signals as shown below and I need to detect if one signal is increasing in amplitude and another in decreasing at the a specific time window and vice versa. I tried findpeaks function but it didn't detect the big peak shown below .. it detects all the small peaks which I don't need them.. any help?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps smoothing followed polynomial fitting would work. Without more details, I can't say. For instance, are there bounds on the SNR of the signals? Will there ever be more than one period of the signal in the time window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `sign(diff(signal))` can help, you can use `sgolayfilt` for noise reduction.

```
L  = 100;
Fs = 50;
t  = (0 : L - 1) / Fs ;
n = .3 * rand([1 L]);
s1 = sin(2 * pi * .8 * t) + n;
s2 = cos(2 * pi * .8 * t) + n;
subplot(311)
plot(t,s1,'b'); hold on
plot(t,s2,'m');
subplot(312)
s1 = sgolayfilt(s1,3,13);
s2 = sgolayfilt(s1,3,13);
t(end) = [];
plot(t,sign(diff(s1)),'b')
ylim([-2 2])
subplot(313)
plot(t,sign(diff(s2)),'m') 
ylim([-2 2])
```

[image]

If your signals are clean then the results will be better.

[image]

Comment: thanks alot Kamtal .. it works fine but I don't understand the number 3 and 13 .. could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @SMH, Thanks for accepting the answer. they are `odd` numbers. the first one is less than the second. for less noisy signal use close values like `11,13` or `5,7` and for noisy signals increase the interval like `3,13` or `3,17`. and check `sgolayfilt`.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the slopes for the period and see whether they have opposing sign.

Comment: Thanks @Peter .. could you please give me an example on any random signals?

Comment: Sure but there will be a delay, I'm busy right now. Essentially you do a line of best fit and get the slope.